# Mysql select dias consecutivos

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tudo certo?! Fiz o select abaixo pra trazer os dias onde tem o evento 99. Se tiver mais de um evento 99 no mesmo dia ele traz o dia somente uma vez. Gostaria de melhorar esse select pra trazer somente quando os dias forem consecutivos.

```
SELECT dt_ini from ocorrencias where cd_motorista = '20427' and cd_status = 99 and dt_ini between date_add('2019-10-21', interval -7 day) and date_add('2019-10-21', interval +1 day) and month(dt_ini) = '10' group by day(dt_ini) order by dt_ini ASC;
```

As datas não são fixas como está aí. Cada dia busca 7 dias pra trás. Até agora o resultado é este:

```
2019-10-14 04:31:00
2019-10-15 06:55:00
2019-10-16 07:42:00
2019-10-17 07:06:00
2019-10-18 06:41:00
2019-10-19 06:13:00
2019-10-21 08:20:00
```

Podem notar que no dia 20 ele não tem evento 99 então não trouxe na consulta. Então este resultado com a melhora no select não deve ser mais apresentado pois não são mais 7 dias consecutivos com evento 99.

Edit:
Preciso que só seja apresentado resultados quando tiver 7 dias consecutivos com evento 99.

Podem me ajudar. Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Não entendi bem o que quer. Poderia melhorar a explicação!?

Comment: @rbz fiz um edit: Preciso que só seja apresentado resultados quando tiver 7 dias consecutivos com evento 99. Nesse exemplo que fiz até agora tá faltando o dia 20 então não deveria ser apresentado.

Comment: Acredito que seu select esteja errado, se eu entendi direito. Para melhorar a sua pergunta, mostre um exemplo dos valores que tem no BD antes do select, os valores depois do select, e os valores que deseja ter. Para ficar melhor ainda, crie um exemplo no [dbfiddle](http://www.db-fiddle.com) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo resolver. Com o select abaixo consigo trazer 7 dias consecutivos caso todos os 7 tenham o evento 99.

```
select if(COUNT(a.cd_ocorrencia) = 7, TRUE, FALSE) as ocorrencia FROM( 
select cd_ocorrencia, dt_ini 
from ocorrencias WHERE cd_motorista = '20427' AND cd_status = 99 
AND dt_ini BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2019-10-06', INTERVAL -6 DAY) AND DATE_ADD('2019-10-06', INTERVAL +1 DAY) 
/*AND MONTH(dt_ini) = '10' */
GROUP BY DAY(dt_ini) 
) a;
```